# Weapons to improve grapple or use in grapple?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, grapple

Are there any weapons or ways to make weapons (e.g. using enchantments) that can improve a character's ability to grapple or provide benefits whilst grappling?

If not, are there any weapons that can be used in a grapple without penalty?

Comment: Have you read the rules on Grappling and the special weapon feature "Grapple"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using weapons during a grapple.

> You can inflict [damage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) to your target equal to your unarmed strike, a
> natural attack, or an attack made with armor spikes or a light or
> one-handed weapon. This damage can be either lethal or nonlethal.

As such, it is likely that most characters will be carrying a suitable weapon to use one a Grapple is initiated.

### Weapons which assist in grappling

There are a number of [weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons) with the [Grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#wpn-quality-grapple) quality that you may find useful:

> **Grapple:** On a successful critical hit with a weapon of this type, you
> can grapple the target of the attack. The wielder can then attempt a
> combat maneuver check to grapple his opponent as a free action. This
> grapple attempt does not provoke an attack of opportunity from the
> creature you are attempting to grapple if that creature is not
> threatening you. While you grapple the target with a grappling weapon,
> you can only move or damage the creature on your turn. You are still
> considered grappled, though you do not have to be adjacent to the
> creature to continue the grapple. If you move far enough away to be
> out of the weapon’s reach, you end the grapple with that action.

I'd also recommend the [dan bong](http://www.pfsdb.com/weapons/dan-bong) which adds an incredibly rare +2 bonus to grapple checks.

> They provide the wielder with the ability to lock an opponent and
> target pressure points that grant her a +2 bonus on her combat
> maneuver to grapple.

Lastly, the [Blade of Binding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/blade-of-binding-1) is a specific magic weapon that has various grappling related abilities.

### Armour

You may also wish to consider the possibility of using the [Brawling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/brawling) enchantment on your armour for the price of a +3 bonus. (It was a +1 bonus at the time this answer was written, but has since gotten an errata.)

> The wearer of brawling armor gains a +2 bonus on unarmed attack and
> damage rolls, including combat maneuver checks made to grapple. ...

Comment: While the Dan Bong adds a bonus to grapple it incurs the -4 penalty for having only one hand free for grappling. _Humanoid creatures without two free hands attempting to grapple a foe take a –4 penalty on the combat maneuver roll._

Comment: @Umbranus Here's probably not the place to disagree, but it's possible that the –4 penalty for using one hand is assessed only when *starting* the grapple, as that's when the penalty's mentioned, and it's never mentioned afterward. Here's an [different context](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#grapple) for comparison to the [*d20PFSRD* context](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple). At any rate, such an alternative reading *does* make the dan bong a little more useful.